# It's possible to keep a socket in a thread running for months in a server without interruption?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, tcplistener

I have a .NET desktop application running on a server, whose function is listen to messages from fingerprint and face recognition devices, and grant access or not.

Sometimes the application stops working. Although it is still running, it appears that it is no longer responding to messages. The users sit forever in front of the device, without the device completing its authentication process (which involves my application).

When this situation arises, I need to restart my application to get everything working again.

The whole process is this:

1. My application opens a TcpListener for each device found (each on a separate thread)
2. My application configures each device to send messages to a specific port.
3. User introduces himself on the device:
4. Device sends userid through a socket client connection to my application
5. My application sends the userid to a backend to validate.
6. Backend responds with true or false
7. My application sends back a signal to the device to grant access or not.
8. Device shows a message to the user
9. Device opens the door if access is granted

In short, the code looks like this:

```
static void Main()
{
  var devices = databaseContext.Devices;
  foreach (var device in devices)
  {
    var server = DeviceServerFactory.GetInstance(device);
    server.Start();
  }
}

class FingerPrintDeviceServer : IDeviceServer
{
  private TcpListener _listener;
  private Thread _thread;
  private bool _running = false;

  public FingerPrintDeviceServer()
  {
    _thread = new Thread(Run);
    _thread.IsBackground = True;
  }

  private async void Run()
  {
    try
    {
      _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverAddr), port);
      _listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
      _listener.Start();

      while(_running)
      {
        await HandleClientConnection();
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Logger.Error(e);
    }
    finally
    {
      _listener.Stop();
    }
  }

  private async Task HandleClientConnection()
  {
    TcpClient client = null;
    NetworkStream stream = null;

    try
    {
      client = mServer.AcceptTcpClient();
      stream = client.GetStream();

      if (stream.CanRead && stream.DataAvailable)
      {
        // Parse the socket byte message and gets the user ID.
        var userId = GetUserId(stream);
        
        // Pass the stream to this class, because this class deals with the authentication rules and uses this stream to send the signal back to the socket client
        var backend = new BackEndClass(stream);
        await backend.validate(userId);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Logger.Error(e);
    }
    finally
    {
      stream?.Dispose();
      client?.Dispose();
    }
  }

  public void Start()
  {
    _running = true;
    _thread.Start();
  }
}
```

Does this design have any problems? Because there is a thread and a listener for each device.

I need these threads and these listeners to work forever. Does a thread or socket have a time limit to operate, or can it run for weeks, months without interruption?

Could the OS (Windows Server) kill a thread if necessary?

Any thoughs will be appreciated!

note: The firewall is out of my control, but the network administrator assured me that he has opened all the ports I needed and nothing is blocking my application (which makes sense as the process stops only sporadically).

Comment: are you missing a GC.KeepAlive() somewhere?

Comment: absolutely, I had no idea the need to make that call. Do I need to call this at the start of the application or for each thread?

Comment: I searched for this, it really could be the problem. I'll fix it and see what happens! Thank you @MitchWheat :)

Answer (score 2):

> Does this design have any problem?

Your `Main()` function is exiting while the server threads are running. You should not exit `Main()` until you are ready to exit the whole program. So `Main()` needs to wait until all of the listeners are done with their work.

Also, checking `stream.CanRead` and `stream.DataAvailable` is not really necessary. Just call `GetUserId()` and let it block until the complete message is received, throwing an error if something goes wrong.

Also, does each device really send only 1 message per TCP connection? That is fairly inefficient, especially if devices reconnect often. At the very least, your server thread should call `GetUserId()` in a loop in case a client decides to send multiple messages. If the client decides to disconnect after the 1st message, then that is on the client, not the server.

Also, does each server really only receive 1 device connection at a time? If there is any possibility of a server handling multiple device connections at a time, then you need to use a separate thread for each accepted client, or at least use asynchronous I/O in your existing server thread, so you can handle multiple messages in parallel.

> Does a thread or socket have a time limit to operate

No.

> can it run for weeks, months without interruption?

Yes.

> Could the OS (Windows Server) kill a thread if necessary?

Not under normal conditions, no. Typically only if an unhandled error is not caught.

Comment: Main function is waiting for threads, forgot to include this in my question, sorry. However, there are very interesting points you raised, I will check all of these and get back to you! In the meantime, thanks for the reply!! :)